# Getting 400 Bad Request When POSTing to Get Transaction Token

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I'm trying to integrate our website with `Converge API` with `Hosted Payments Page`.  Here is the link to their documentation https://developer.elavon.com/#/api/eb6e9106-0172-4305-bc5a-b3ebe832f823.rcosoomi/versions/5180a9f2-741b-439c-bced-5c84a822f39b.rcosoomi/documents?converge-integration-guide/book/integration_methods/../../book/integration_methods/hosted_payments.html

I'm having troubles getting past the first step which is requesting a transaction token from their API endpoint.  I'm sending a `POST` request from my server using `axios` with the correct parameters and URL, but when I try and `POST` i get `400 Bad Request`.  When I make the same request in `POSTMAN` I get a `200 response` with the transaction token.  I talked to their developers and they said that everything I was doing was correct and that nothing seemed odd within my code, so even they were stumped as to why I couldn't make a `POST` request to their endpoint.  Obviously there is something within my code that their API is not liking, or else I wouldn't be here trying to find answers for this.

Here is how I'm making the POST request:

```
app.get('/converge_token_req', (request, response) => {

    let params = {
        ssl_merchant_id: '*****',
        ssl_user_id: '*****',
        ssl_pin: '*****',
        ssl_transaction_type: 'ccsale',
        ssl_amount: '1.00'
    }

    axios.post('https://api.demo.convergepay.com/hosted-payments/transaction_token', params, {
        headers: { 'Content_Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then((res) => {
        response.send(res.data)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('there was an error getting transaction token')
        response.send(error.message)
    })

})
```

Here are the Request Headers:

[image]

I'm honestly out of ideas to try.  The developers say that everything looks just fine yet I'm unable to make a successful request to their API.  If anyone has any thoughts on this that would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This code below worked for me:

```
app.get('/converge_token_req', (request, response) => {

let params = {
    ssl_merchant_id: '*****',
    ssl_user_id: '*****',
    ssl_pin: '*****',
    ssl_transaction_type: 'ccsale',
    ssl_amount: '1.00'
}

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.demo.convergepay.com/hosted-payments/transaction_token',
    params: params
    }).then((res) => { response.send(res.data)
    }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('there was an error getting transaction token: ', 
    error)
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've since found out the solution to my problem.  The issue here is that converge expects a `x-www-form-urlencoded` string that needs to be `Stringified` before submitting the request.  I found a library that works well for this called `qs` and I used it like so:

```
let params = qs.stringify({ // need this if content_type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            ssl_merchant_id: env.CONVERGE.MERCHANT_ID,
            ssl_user_id: env.CONVERGE.USER_ID,
            ssl_pin: env.CONVERGE.PIN,
            ssl_transaction_type: request.query.type,
            ssl_amount: request.query.amount,
            ssl_email: request.query.email,
            ssl_company: request.query.company,
            ssl_avs_address: request.query.address,
            ssl_avs_zip: request.query.zip,
            ssl_description: request.query.desc,
        })
    
        axios.post('https://api.convergepay.com/hosted-payments/transaction_token', params, {
            headers: { 
                'Content_Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' 
            }
        }).then((res) => {
            response.send(res.data)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('there was an error getting transaction token')
            response.send(error.message)
        })
```

I think you could also get away with just using `JSON.stringify()` but this way worked for me.